# Assigning variable in document.getElementById(#div).innerHTML by radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

folks!

I have a form with 40 radio type inputs and I have 40 cells with the same value.

I take capturing the radio send and assign to document.getElementById (VARIAVEL) .innerHTML.

I can retrieve the value of the radio and display on the screen with 'echo', but I can not send the information to the corresponding cell in the table with the document.getElementById (#id) .innerHTML, which leads me to believe that I do not I'm sure how to set it up.

I would want the radio value to set in which cell the content will be displayed.

I have looked at several books and I have not found it and on the internet what I have just confused.

I retrieve the value of the radio and I can see it on the screen with 'echo' but I can not send the information to the corresponding cell with the document.getElementById (#id) .innerHTML. I already looked at several books and I did not find it and on the internet what I found just confused me.

The code to better understand my question would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="value1"></div></td>
<td><div id="value2"></div></td>
<td><div id="value3"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

<form action="script.php" id="test" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input value="value1" name="idradio" type="radio" />valor1</td>
<input value="value2" name="idradio" type="radio" />valor2</td>
<input value="value3" name="idradio" type="radio" />valor3</td>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var content = "Any content";
var var_id_radio = '<?php echo $_GET['idradio'];?>';
document.getElementById(var_id_radio).innerHTML=content;
</script>
```

p.s.: I know that the variable "var_id_radio" is not placed in that way, this is precisely the reason for the question, I do not know how to setting the variable (), I think I can do, but I have not found it yet. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try `var var_id_radio = "<?php echo $_GET['idradio'];?>"; alert( var_id_radio );`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately the document.getElementById().InnerHTML does not recognize the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve value from PHP code like that.
PHP runs on server, but Javascript runs on the client side.
You can pass PHP Variables to your JavaScript by generating it with PHP:

```
// script.php
<?php 
    $radioValue = $_GET['idradio']; 
?>

// JAVASCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
    var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $radioValue; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the document.getElementById( var here ).InnerHTML does not recognize the variable. This would be perfect...

Comment: How about you do console.log(javaScriptVar) to check it. It should be equal to some radio id.